# External table KUP-04021: field formatting error for field load issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The external table defined with below conditions to load data from file to table.This is running in prod for long time no issues .

```
    We started having this issue for below field
    **KUP-04021: field formatting error for field column3
    KUP-04026: field too long for datatype**
```

The column length of data is approx 625 characters and column3 in external tables defined like varchar(1300 BYTE)

```
    The value below is causing the issue 
    (170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),48553(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),68872(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),70421(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),73578(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75622(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75706(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75837(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75875(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),76193(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),81896(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),83905(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),84206(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),84840(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),87215(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),662(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),732(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0)
```

External table definition which currently in place and have issues for above data load.

```
CREATE TABLE DADM.LOAD_EXT
(
    COLUMN1                         VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    COLUMN2                         VARCHAR2(26   BYTE),
    COLUMN3                         VARCHAR2(1300 BYTE),
    COLUMN4                         VARCHAR2(30   BYTE)

)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXT_DATA_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      BADFILE EXT_BAD_DIR:'file.bad'
      LOGFILE EXT_LOG_DIR:'file.log'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LRTRIM
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
      REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
      NULLIF = "null"
      (
        COLUMN1, 
        COLUMN2 ,
        COLUMN3, 
        COLUMN4         
        )
     )
     LOCATION (EXT_DATA_DIR:'extract_file_.dat_tr')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
/
```

Data for above external table

L-5772559|None|48526(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),48553(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),68872(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),70421(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),73578(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75622(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75706(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75837(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),75875(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),76193(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),81896(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),83905(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),84206(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),84840(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),87215(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),662(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0),732(170KB ACCT SHR $0.00003/KB $0)|00058

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include the field definitions for this table. Also, what's your database charset? Thanks.

Comment: @Bob , I have added the external table defn

Comment: Approx 625 characters not fitting in a 1300 Byte VARCHAR2: sound to me as a multibyte character / length semantics problem. Can you retry in a test database where the external table is set to `VARCHAR2(1300 CHAR)`. I bet the problem will go away...

Comment: That's why I asked OP for the database character set. @kanagaraj: please execute the following query and report the results: `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` Thanks.

Comment: @wol , I tried in lower environments I see one issue the value for this field is pulling NULL when I change to VARCHAR2(1300 CHAR)

Comment: @Bob , The value is 'AL32UTF8'

Comment: Well, that makes some sense as AL32UTF8 is a multi-byte character set - basically a superset of Unicode UTF-8. However, none of the characters that I see are outside of the Latin-1 portion of the character set (code points U+0000 - U+007F), so they should encode in a single byte. Could you please add the entire line from your data file that's having problems to the question? Thanks.

Comment: @Bob , makes sense .. I have added the data for single record

Comment: I grabbed the text from the question above, pasted it into my programming editor in a UTF-8 buffer, saved it - and it's only 645 bytes, exactly what I'd expect for all ASCII/Latin-1 characters. I'm running out of ideas here. If you cut your input file down to just one record, how long is the file? I'm wondering if perhaps its an issue caused by the file being encoded in something like UTF-16 or UCS-2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215346/discussion-between-kanagaraj-and-bob-jarvis-reinstate-monica).

Comment: yes Bob , length is not an issue but something with that field .... since all records coming in single line and I dont see any length more. The file contain just 277 records of those 83 records with these values causing issues . Thanks for valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE 18c

If you look at your LOGFILE:

```
...
  Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Reject rows with all null fields
  Table level NULLIF (Field = null)
  Fields in Data Source: 

    COLUMN1                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by "|"
      Trim whitespace from left and right
    COLUMN2                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by "|"
      Trim whitespace from left and right
    COLUMN3                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by "|"
      Trim whitespace from left and right
...
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field COLUMN3
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype
KUP-04101: record 1 rejected in file 
...
```

So, it seems, that ORACLE reads 255 bytes by default and you didn't specified CHAR length within the source. Solution is:

```
...
NULLIF = "null" (
            COLUMN1,
            COLUMN2,
            COLUMN3 CHAR(1300), 
            COLUMN4         
        )
...
```

LOGFILE after the solution was implemented:

```
...
    COLUMN2                         CHAR (255)
      Terminated by "|"
      Trim whitespace from left and right
    COLUMN3                         CHAR (1300)
      Terminated by "|"
      Trim whitespace from left and right
    COLUMN4                         CHAR (255)
...
```

Comment: can you please mention the name of the LOG file?

Comment: @NadeemTaj, log file names specified during external table creation in the ACCESS PARAMETERS section: ACCESS PARAMETERS (...BADFILE DIR:'filename' LOGFILE DIR:'filename'...)